# Generate unique list from a list of lists

Tags: python, unique, python-3.4

I'm trying to define a function that will accept an arbitrary number of lists and will generate a single list of unique elements from those lists. (I'm using Python 3.4)

Example:

```
a = ['lion', 'tiger', 'panther']
b = ['dog', 'lion', 'bear']
c = ['rat', 'dog', 'tiger']

def merge(*var_list):
    newlist = []
    for item in var_list:
        newlist.append(item)
    return newlist
```

Evaluating:

```
merge(a,b)
```

Produces:

```
[['lion', 'tiger', 'panther'], ['dog', 'lion', 'bear']]
```

Ideally, I would like it to generate a list that looks like this:

```
['lion, 'tiger', 'panther', 'dog', 'bear']  #order is not important
```

How can I achieve the above result?

Comment: Can you assume the elements in each original list are unique?  (It simplifies/speeds-up things a bit if you can.)

Comment: Did you miss rat from your expected result?

Comment: The items in `var_list` are the *lists* you passed to merge, which is why your result is a list of lists, and not just a list of strings (as you desired).

Comment: @klashxx "rat" is not in the output, as he only merged a and b. See "Evaluating: merge(a,b)". If he were to merge a b and c, then use, rat would be in the output.

Comment: I see, answer just updated. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
list(set(a+b))
```

As Greg explain in comments, `Python` treat each list as a `set`, where a *set* has the property of *being composed* of unordered unique elements.

By adding sets together, you will be able to keep the property of *unordered-ness*.

From the interpreter:

```
>>> a+b
['lion', 'tiger', 'panther', 'dog', 'lion', 'bear']
>>> list(set(a+b))
['tiger', 'lion', 'dog', 'bear', 'panther']
```

Comment: A small explanation would be nice. This works because this code has Python treat each list as a set, where a set has the property of being composed of ordered unique elements. By adding sets together, you will be able to keep the property of unordered-ness and arrive at your solution.

Comment: Thanks @GregHilston , can't be better explained. Allow me to use your words

Comment: No problem. +1 for the solution and interpreter output. Quick and clean.

Comment: Thanks everyone! However, how would I incorporate the set() function into my original code? I need to be able to do define a function that will yield the same result as "list(set(a+b)). Cheers!

Comment: Do you mean to emulate set , but not using it ?

Comment: set() is a built in function. So just call it! Also, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Yes, klashxx perhaps without using it. When I call the set() function in my original code- return set(newlist) I'm getting a TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: It isn't pretty, but I came up with this:                             >>> def merge(*var_list): newlist = [] for i in var_list: if i not in newlist: newlist.append(i) while len(newlist)> 0: return list(set([item for sublist in newlist for item in sublist]))